# Is there a way to refile a table row or a line?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm using refile in a table, but it tries to move all the table, not the line I'm in, if refile cannot move a table-row i think a more general way would be to move the line itself, without knowing if is a list-item, table row, or whatever, do you guys know how to set this? Thanks a lot

Comment: How about simply blocking and cutting the line, and pasting it somewhere else?  There are commands to jump to a heading, and also isearch can be used to get to where you want to go.